# my machine crashes after inserting the following kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, kernel-module

I am a total beginner in kernel module programming. I wanted to create a module which reads input from the proc filesystem. With this you should be able to perform operations in the program. I did that with threading. However my machine crashes after inserting the module. Probably I did something wrong. Here is the source code:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/wait.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

#define PROCFS_MAX_SIZE 1024
#define PROCFS_NAME "test"

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

int pid = 1;
static struct proc_dir_entry *Our_Proc_File;
static char procfs_buffer[PROCFS_MAX_SIZE];
static unsigned long procfs_buffer_size = 0;
struct task_struct *task;

static ssize_t procfile_read(struct file *file, char *buffer, size_t buffer_length, loff_t *offset) {
    static int flag = 0;
    if(flag) {
      printk(KERN_INFO "read : END\n");
        flag = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "read (/proc/%s) : called\n",PROCFS_NAME);
    flag = 1;
    return snprintf(buffer, buffer_lengh, procfs_buffer);
}

static ssize_t procfile_write(struct file *file,const char *buffer, size_t count, loff_t *offset) {
        procfs_buffer_size = count;
        if (copy_from_user(procfs_buffer, buffer, procfs_buffer_size)) {
                return -EFAULT;
        }
        return procfs_buffer_size;
}

static int main_prog(void *data) {
    int end = 0;
    while(!end) {
        while(memcmp(procfs_buffer,"\x00",1)==0);
        if(memcmp(procfs_buffer,"test",4)) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Test triggered!\n");
        }
        if(memcmp(procfs_buffer,"exit",4)) {
            end++;
        }
        memset(procfs_buffer, 0, 1024);
    }
    kthread_stop(task);
}

static struct file_operations fops_struct = {
    .read = procfile_read,
    .write = procfile_write,
};

int init_module() {
        Our_Proc_File = proc_create(PROCFS_NAME, 0666, NULL, &fops_struct);
        if (Our_Proc_File == NULL) {
                remove_proc_entry(PROCFS_NAME, NULL);
                printk(KERN_ALERT "Error: Could not initialize /proc/%s\n", PROCFS_NAME);
                return -ENOMEM;
        }
        task = kthread_run(&main_prog, NULL, "thread");
        wake_up_process(task);
        printk(KERN_INFO "/proc/%s created\n", PROCFS_NAME);
        return 0;
}

void cleanup_module() {
        remove_proc_entry(PROCFS_NAME, NULL);
        printk(KERN_INFO "/proc/%s removed\n", PROCFS_NAME);
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `sprintf(buffer, procfs_buffer);` What if `buffer` has 1 byte? ie. what you think `buffer_length` is for?

Comment: Your thread looks like 100% CPU usage forever. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: @stark do I need to use `kthread_bind` to fix it?

Comment: No. You need to make it event-driven instead of an infinite loop.

Comment: @stark sorry but I don't know how to do that, could you give me a little example please?

Comment: "However my machine crashes after inserting the module." - Have you tried to detect what exact line crashes your machine? E.g., would the machine crash if you don't create a thread (that is, if remove `kthread_run` and `wake_up_process` lines)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev no, the machine crashes because of the thread. If I remove the lines it doesn't crash

Comment: As you expect your buffer to be initially empty, then before any attempt to write or read your file in procfs the loop `while(memcmp(procfs_buffer,"\x00",1)==0);` should continue forever. Have you tried to leave only this loop in your thread function? (This is only for debug possible cause of system crashing). Note also, that calling `kthread_stop` inside the **thread itself** is wrong. The correct way to terminate the current thread is executing `return <value>;`. Also, calling `wake_up_process` after `kthread_run` is useless: `kthread_run` is shortcut for `kthread_create`+`wake_up_process`.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "my machine crashes"? Does it show an error message? Or does it freeze (do not respond)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I am connected via ssh and immedeatly after insmod the connection is dead

Comment: When a crash occurs, the kernel prints an error and stack trace to the console.  When the kernel stops responding, because it is in a deadlock, interrupt routine or infinite loop, that's a hang.

Comment: It seems like it is because the infinite loop. Is there a way to make an infinite loop in a kernel module which does not cause a hangup or crash?

Comment: What is the reason for doing `remove_proc_entry()` right after failing `proc_create()`? It's useless. There's nothing to remove.

Comment: Also you must check the result of `kthread_run()` before handling the `task` structure.